# Copy Aptana-projects and connections from one computer to another

Tags: text-editors, web-development, aptana-studio

Is there a way to copy all the projects, connections and settings of Aptana Studio3 on one computer to another one running the exact same version of Aptana Studio3.

The projects actually only exists of remote connections, and no local files.

Does anyone have a walk through or guide?

Answer (score 1):

To backup all the projects.

1. Open  aptana studio.
2. Click on the project explorer tab.
3. Select all the projects except local file system.
4. Right click and choose export.
5. Click on general folder.
6. Click on Archive file.
7. Click next.
8. Click browse and choose the location for export file.
9. Make sure that you checked zip or tar format.
10. Check compress the contents of file.
11. Check create directory structure for files.
12. Click on finish it will took take a minutes to finish.

To import your backup.

1. Click on file.
2. Click on import.
3. Choose general folder.
4. Choose "existing projects into workspace" then next.
5. Check select archive file then use browse button for selecting your backup file.
6. After that you will see your projects click on select all button.
7. Click on finish.

Note: These steps will not import your "connections".

To backup your connections:

1. Find your workspace in your old computer folder and follow this location:

   C:\Users\your username\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace.metadata.plugins\com.aptana.core.io
2. Open the connections.number file with notepad.
3. Copy content.

To import your connections:

1. Find your workspace in your new computer and follow the same location:
   C:\Users\your username\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace.metadata.plugins\com.aptana.core.io
2. Open the connetions.number file with notepad.
3. Paste the content.

Answer (score 1):

To transfer the passwords on remote connections:

1. Transfer remote connections as explained by motto. This copies the connections but not the passwords. The rest of these steps copy the passwords.
2. On the source machine, preferences->General->Security->Secure Storage
3. Change Password. When prompted for enabling password recovery, click YES
4. Enter security questions and answers as prompted. Make sure to retain the exact answers.
5. Still in preferences for Secure Storage, click the Contents tab. Copy or memorize the storage location (full path).
6. On the target machine, verify the location where secure_storage is saved, by viewing Preferences->General->Security->Secure Storage
7. Quit Aptana on source and target machines.
8. Copy the file called secure_storage from the source machine, replacing the secure_storage file on the target machine.
9. Start Aptana on target machine.
10. Preferences->General->Security->Secure Storage
11. In the passwords tab, click Recover Password
12. Answer the security questions (created in step 4, above). At this point, the remote connections will work. Exception: connections using sftp work only if you already have copied ssh keys from target machine to the machines hosting the remote connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a mac, the path for the connections is as follows:

```
~/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/com.aptana.core.io
```

Are the passwords for FTP connections stored in the keychain?

Comment: Unfortunately Aptana doesn't save passwords in that file. Someone knows where it stores the passwords?